# Traverse SQL hierarchy from bottom up till specific level reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table will a few hundred services that I am scraping from a third party web service. The services have several million symbols which I'm also getting.

The hierarchy is essentially this;

```
root
|_service1
| |_service1/sub1*
| |_service1/sub2
| |_service1/sub3
| |_service1/sub4
| | |_service1/sub4/sub1
| |   |_**service1/sub4/sub1/leaf1**
| |
| |_service1/sub5
|
|_service2
  |_service2/sub1 
  |_service2/sub2
  |_service2/sub3
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is - given an Id for a leaf, I want to work up the tree till I find the branch were isActive is true then return that value.

In this example, I want to find the active service for the leaf `/service1/sub4/sub1/leaf1` which in this case is `service1/sub1`

Up to now I've been using a Common Table Expression to work from the top down and set an additional ActiveServiceId column on the leaves that are under that branch; with millions of symbols that turns into a very long running process.

I'm only working with a very small subset of the symbols (although I don't know which ones and I need them all) so the known leaf Ids at the time of the query will only be a few hundred.

I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/838b04/5) to reflect this hierachy to assist anyone who might be able to help

**UPDATE** to explain further the current approach. If I decided that `service1` is to be the new active service - the leaves under service1 in every sub branch need to bubble up to service1 and I will reset all the child branches so none of them as marked as active

Comment: have you considered using hierarchical data types?: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

Comment: I've just read up on this, useful information to now have but I don't think it's going to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it useful to use nested sets to store this data:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

I have used this method before to store tree data in a database and found it good for querying data belonging to all nodes under a parent etc.

Using the data stored in nested sets the solution to your problem would be as follows:

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM TreeTable s
WHERE s.L = (SELECT Max(t.L)
            FROM TreeTable t, TreeTable LeafNode
            WHERE t.isActive = true
              AND t.L < LeafNode.L
              AND t.R > LeafNode.R
              AND LeafNode.ID = ?)
```

Comment: This seems to make sense, I'm just trying to work out how I'm going to create the tables for this and add the data. I think I understand the gist of the model.

Comment: It looks like to add nodes I need to push out right and left by the number of added nodes, is that correct understanding? Any nicer way to add lots at a time?

Comment: Yes that's right. You increase the right of all the higher nodes by the size of the node (the right - left of it) you're going to add in + 1. So to add a new leaf node to a parent which has L=6 R=7 you:
    UPDATE TreeTable
    SET R = R + 2
    WHERE R >= 7
Then
    INSERT INTO TreeTable(L,R) VALUES(7,8)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full path stored as a string for each node you can do the following:

```
SELECT r.ID
FROM TreeTable r, TreeTable rs
WHERE rs.ID = ?
  AND r.Path = Left(rs.path,Len(r.Path))
  AND Len(r.Path) = (SELECT Max(Len(t.Path))
                     FROM TreeTable t, TreeTable s
                     WHERE s.ID = ?
                       AND t.Path = Left(s.path,Len(t.Path))
                       AND t.isActive = true)
```

Ok it's not pretty and I welcome any suggestions for making it neater - but it should work.

Comment: no, that was for the example, probably not helpful to have done it that way after all